# Guidance on Merge Sort Algorithm

Tags: merge, mips, mergesort

Currently working on a class assignment to create a merge sort algorithm using MIPS assembly language. Ill paste the instructions to said assignment to make sure my interpretation of what I'm supposed to do is correct.

The Instructions:

Convert "merge" in Assignment 3 (**Assignment 3 is a merge algorithm that takes two ordered lists merges all elements of that list into one long ordered list, I've already completed this**) into a subroutine. Write a "main" program to perform merge-sorting of a list of integers by calling "merge" repeatedly ( ** Im assuming this means calling my previous Assignment 3**). For example, if the sorting program takes (6,5,9,1,7,0,-3,2) as input, it will produce a sorted list (-3,0,1,2,4,6,7,9). 
The original unsorted list of integers should be received from the keyboard input. Your program should first ask for the user to input the number of integers in the original list, and then ask for inputting all the integers. The total number of integers to be sorted by this program should be a power of 2. This means, the program should work with a list of 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32 (...) integers (but your program needs only to handle up to 32 integers).

Now, my merge algorithm takes two ordered lists but this assignment takes only 1 list. However, the link bellow explains merge sort in a way where the original unsorted list is progressively divided up into individual elements and then it works backwards and puts the elements in order. (**Since my assignment 3 (the merge algorithm that i already have) takes two ordered lists would it be possible for me to simply do one iteration of my merge algorithm right after dividing the unsorted list into two unsorted lists??**)

Basically, calling my merge algorithm at the second step in the bellow link.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/merge_sort_algorithm.htm

Thank you so much!

Comment: this site is not doing your homework

Comment: If anyone else is also needing this question answered. Basically, you need to divide the original unordered list again and again till you get to its individual elements. My previous assumption that I could use the a merge algorithm right after dividing into two was wrong because that list won't necessarily be ordered, however, when you dive the list into individual elements then a list of only 1 element is always ordered. You then apply merge to the individual elements till you get the full list but it will now be in order.  Hope that helps, I know others in my class had the same question.